# An internal error occurred during: "Retrieving archetypes:". Java heap space when creating new Maven project

Tags: java, maven

I am starting to learn Spring, So i am creating to new Maven project in eclipse.

When i am trying to create a new Maven project , then it tries to retrieve archetype and gives the error

```
"An internal error occurred during: "Retrieving archetypes:"
Java heap space
```

[image: Error window when creating maven project]

Steps that i followed : 
New -> Maven Project -> use default worksppace location (checked) and click Next -> waiting for retrieving archetype and error occurs.

I have attached the screen shot for reference.

Note : I have been trying to resolve this for hours, searched google and stack exchange, changed -Xmx size to 1024m from 512m in elclipse.ini file and tried to restart the eclipse, but that time eclipse refused to launch.
Also 
'Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Download repository updates index on startup' is NOT enabled in my eclpise as suggested in other answer to similar question in stackoverflow to disable it.

Please help me out with this.

Comment: What happens if you try to run maven from command line? `mvn archetype:generate` ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos it downloads lot of files and then ask for 
"Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): 966:) : "
I don't know what to do at this stage.

Comment: Then try to configure the external maven in eclipse and use it.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I configured external maven in eclipse, but still i am getting the same error at same point when trying to create new maven project

Comment: Then increase the eclipse permgen space. On eclipse ini add these parameters: `-XX:PermSize=512M -XX:MaxPermSize=6144M` and test it. Read it here to see if you didn't get something wrong when you first try it: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_permgen_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

Comment: Seems like a bug, I temporally solve the issue disabling Nexus indexer.

Windows->Preferences->Maven->Archetypes.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested by Jorge Campos in the comments above, I increased Eclipse's `PermGen` space. On `eclipse.ini` add these parameters and restart Eclipse:

```
-XX:PermSize=512M 
-XX:MaxPermSize=6144M
```

Its working now.

Comment: I had the same issue, I copied -XX:PermSize=512M -XX:MaxPermSize=6144M and pasted it, at the end of the ini file and saved it, restart eclipse finally it works.

Answer (score 3):

Just clear your data in eclipse.ini copy paste below code into it 
since your default memory is lesser than required, it is not able to retrieve archetype

-----------------------eclipse.ini---------------------------

```
-startup
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms512m
-Xmx6144m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

---

Answer (score 3):

Your workspace somehow got corrupted.

If you switch your workspace and try to create a new maven project the issue will be gone.

Just in case: You can switch your workspace from File > Switchworkspace > ...
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Switching the Workspace fixed it for me. File | Switch Workspace

Comment: Thank you buddy, I realized this was the answer after reinstalling Eclipse

Comment: Did you figure out a way to "clean" the "corrupted" workspace?

Comment: @FedericoDestefanis No I havn't. Probably some issue in <workspace>/.metadata/.plugins Just backup Eclipse settings and create another workspace.

Answer (score 0):

the same thing did happen to me, what i did is just restarting my laptop and it did work

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was from the internet network I was using. When connecting my laptop to my hotspot mobile data instead, everything works fine.